# bitbucket pipelines: run pipeline only on PR create, not PR update?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Bitbucket allows to start pipeline for a PR:

```
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    "**":
      - step:
          script:
            - echo "First step"
```

And this pipeline runs on both PR creations and updates. Every single push to a branch for this PR reruns it.

Is there a way to run a pipeline only on PR creations but not on updates?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late, but hopefully this helps someone. I would try something like:

```
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    "**":
      - step:
          name: 'Run Once'
          caches:
            - hasrun
          script:
            - ./pr-cache.sh
  branches:
    main:
      - step:
          name: 'Clear Cache'
          caches:
            - hasrun
          script:
            - rm prs/*

definitions:
  caches:
    hasrun: prs/
```

The trick is the use of caches. Here, `pr-cache.sh` just checks if a file with the PR id already exists. If it does, nothing happens. Otherwise, it creates the file, and does stuff.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir prs 2>/dev/null
if [[ -f prs/$BITBUCKET_PR_ID.txt ]]; then
    echo "Not doing a thing" # PR pipeline has already been run once.
else
    echo $BITBUCKET_PR_ID > prs/$BITBUCKET_PR_ID.txt
    echo "Doing a thing" # PR pipeline has not been run yet
fi
```

Since the `prs` folder is cached, the pr file will be available for the next build.

It's not perfect. There's currently no way to know which PR triggered a build in `branches` steps, so the only way to clear that PR from the cache is to delete the entire folder. There is an [open feature request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-20888) to make `$BITBUCKET_PR_ID` available to all pipeline steps, not just `pull-requests`.

Once that feature is made available, I would replace the `rm prs/*` line with `rm prs/$BITBUCKET_PR_ID.txt`.

Until then, **this solution will clear the cache for all PRs when any one is merged**. That means it should drastically *reduce* the number of reruns. If your PR creation is very synchronous, this could be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am very late to reply on this, but as per updated documentation:

> If you ever want to push a commit and skip triggering its pipeline,
> you can add `[skip ci]` or `[ci skip]` to the commit message.

Further Reading: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/pipeline-start-conditions/#Pull-Requests